# Physical significance and graphical point of view of second derivative of a function $f''(x)$ .

Tags: functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

This was just going through my mind - $f'(x)$ represents slope of a function. Then what does $f''(x)$ represent?

For example, we define strictly increasing and strictly decreasing functions in some parts as follows:

**Strictly Increasing functions** : ( If $x_1 < x_2$ then $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ ) for all $x$ belonging to the domain of the function.

Graphically we may represent it as: [image: Source: AskIITians.com]

Now, it can be classified as :

$(i)$ **Concave up when** $f'(x) > 0$ and $ f''(x) > 0 \ \forall \ x \in \text{domain} $

$(ii)$ **When** $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) = 0$ ; $\forall x \in \text{domain}$

[image: y = x]

$(iii)$ **Concave down when** $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) < 0 , \ \forall x \in \text{domain}$

Similarly, these classifications can be done for **Strictly Decreasing Functions**. To sum up, following image describes:

[image: Paul Notes]

Now, as you might have noticed, there is second derivative coming into play in order to define the *shape* of the graph, that is, it is whether *concave up* or *concave down*. I'm a bit confused that how did it help in deciding the shape of the graph...!

Is their any **graphical representation** for second derivative of a function? Any physical significance of $f''$ ?

Comment: Your question is about the second derivative (it is not called the "double derivative") but the subject line ends with $f'''$. Fix that.

Comment: Oh, am sorry! One sec.

Comment: Btw, what is the difference between double derivative and second derivative? Why aren't they same?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "double derivative."  It's like asking why in a sequence $a_1, a_2,\dots$ we don't call $a_2$ the "double term." It's just not the term that is used.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second derivative represents the inflexion of a curve at a given point. In the picture you have given, it shows the concavity of the graph of function. When the concavity is turned up, the second derivative is positive; otherwise it is negative. When it is zero, the graph of function inflects at that point; that is, the graph has an S-shaped form at the point.

Physically, the second derivative of the function of position of a body in respect to time gives the acceleration of the body along the time. The second derivative of the function of load in a building beam is related to the internal forces that deform the beam.

Comment: I'm a bit confused in this. Can you explain with the help of a graph? S-shaped form at the point, sorry, can't get it too! :(

Comment: I guess I got it now! Referred to : https://math.dartmouth.edu/opencalc2/cole/lecture8.pdf . Thanks to you, earlier I was totally blind about second derivative. Got it finally, thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://clas.sa.ucsb.edu/staff/lee/inflection%20pt%20x%5E3%20with%20f(x).gif) (posted on May 1st, 2015)

Comment: Great! Thanks again! I appreciate all your efforts, Mr. Marcelo!

Comment: it is not true that $f''(x) = 0$ implies $(x,f(x))$ is a point of inflection. look at $y = x^4$ and the point $(0,0).$  what is true is that if $f''$ changes sign across $x,$  then $(x,f(x)$ is a point of in flexion.

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative of a function has a lot to do with the curvature, e.g. it's given by
$$\kappa=\frac{|y''|}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
whereas the signed curvature is given by
$$k=\frac{y''}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
Then we have for example: $k>0 \Leftrightarrow y$ strictly convex